# Label Arbitrary Edges as Axes for 3D Graphics

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, labeling, visualization

In any 3D plot in Mathematica, there are 12 edges that, theoretically, can be labeled as axes. We can use `AxesEdge` to label some combinations, but not any combination. The documentation shows this.

[image: 1]

Notice the specification of only three edges. Moreover, I would like to label *any combination* to be respective axes (for, at least, `ListLinePlot3D`) and for the plot to be able to be rotated in 3D as usual (so `Overlay` doesn't work). Is there a nice way of doing this?

For example, I would like the following, but because `Overlay` is used, the graphic loses functionality such as the ability to be rotated and as well as "right click" functionality like copying.

```
list = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2}, {2, 4, 3}, {3, 6, 
    4}};

Overlay[{
  ListLinePlot3D[list, Axes -> True, 
   AxesEdge -> {{1, -1}, None, None}, AxesLabel -> {"axis", ""}],
  ListLinePlot3D[list, Axes -> True, 
   AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, None, None}, AxesLabel -> {"axis", ""}]
  }]
```

[image]

Notice, unlike with 2D plots, 3D plots do not have frame options to help us here.

Any ideas?

Comment: Would you know the `PlotRange` in advance? If so, you might be able to somehow make the axes yourself? Just an idea, but the answer to my first question should provide clarification to anyone who can answer.

Comment: @CATrevillian I’d be ok with knowing it in advance.

Comment: I'd place them manually, perhaps with `Epilog->{Line[...],Line[...],text3D[...],...}` and label them with `text3D` if you want rotatable labels (search for it here).